# How to elide the final page number in compressed page ranges for Biblatex backrefs?

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I have edited this question to add a MWE below.

I am preparing camera-ready copy of a book for an academic press, and I have to conform to their house style.  For indexes, they stipulate that page ranges have to be elided to their smallest form, except for numbers less than 20.  In other words, the range 190--191 should be elided to 190--1, the range 156--163 becomes 156--63, 42--49 becomes 42--9, and 11--17 stays unchanged.

I have been able to implement the press specification for my two indexes by writing a Perl script that modifies the .idx files, runs makeindex, and modifies the resulting .ind files.  But eliding the page ranges for the compressed Biblatex backreferences will be trickier, since the ranges are generated by Biblatex from the aux file which changes on every run, rather than externally from .ind files that Latex does not touch.

I have looked at the Biblatex code, and it seems that I would have to modify the pageref:comp and pageref:dump macros, but that is beyond my competence.

So I have experimented with modifying the .aux file by changing and removing lines starting with \abx@aux@backref.  I can delete the lines for a given page range and replace it with a line that inserts the appropriately elided range, like so:
\abx@aux@backref{375}{Foobar:1967}{0}{84--5}{84--5}

A quick, manual test shows that this works, though I have worries about automating it.  The entries in the .aux file are numbered consecutively, so I am afraid that deleting some may induce buggy behavior.  This approach also requires running the Perl script to modify the .aux file after every run, which would be easy to forget to do.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm very grateful to the contributors to this site; I would not have been able to implement the minutiae of the press spec without the information I found here.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref=true,backrefstyle=two]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

% We only want elision to happen after page 20
XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}  
XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}
XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}
XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}
XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}XXX\clearpage{}

Page 20: \cite{Knu86}\clearpage
Page 21: \cite{Knu86}\clearpage
Page 22: \cite{Knu86}\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What this generates for the bibliography is the following  output:
Knuth, Donald E. (1986). The TEXbook (cit. on pp. 20–22).

I need that back-reference page range to read "(cit. on pp. 20–2)." with the second number in the page range abbreviated from 22 to 2.  I hope that makes my question clearer.

Comment: Please consider adding the name of the academic press, so future users with the same problem can find this question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following. Attention: It is not a completly general solution. It makes a few assumption, e.g. that you only have arabic pagenumbers (a roman number e.g. would give a missing number error), and that you don't need hyperlinks. Also I didn't tested it much, so I could have missed some details. It uses the internal commands of the `\mkcomprange`, so the exact compressing behaviour can (probably) be affected by the counters `mincomprange` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\firstpagetemp{}
\newcommand\printsecondrangevalue{}
\def\printsecondrangevalue #1\bibrangedash #2{#2}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{pageref:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\abx@range@diff}{0}
    {\edef\firstpagetemp{\the\numexpr\abx@range@hold-\abx@range@diff}%
     \bibrangedash
     \ifnum\firstpagetemp<20
      \abx@range@hold
     \else
      \def\blx@tempa{}%
      \protected\def\blx@range@out@value{\appto\blx@tempa}%
      \edef\next{\noexpand\blx@comprange@comp {\firstpagetemp}{\abx@range@hold}}%
      \next
      \expandafter\printsecondrangevalue\blx@tempa
    \fi%
    \def\abx@range@diff{0}}{}%
    }

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{10}
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,9}
{\cite{weinberg}\newpage}

blub \newpage blub

\foreach\x in {1,2,...,8}
{\cite{weinberg}\newpage}

blub \newpage blub
\setcounter{page}{100}

\foreach\x in {1,2,...,28}
{\cite{weinberg}\newpage}

blub \newpage blub

\cite{herrmann}\cite{weinberg}\clearpage
\cite{weinberg}\clearpage
\cite{herrmann}\cite{weinberg}\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks so much!  I don't mind that it does not work with Roman numerals, since I do not have any ranges in that part of the book.  The fact that the page number at end of the range does not have a hyperlink is not a problem, since there is a hyperlink for the page at the start of the range.  This book is for Oxford University Press, but all of the other academic presses I have worked with have also wanted their indexes to be formatted in this fashion, so it would be great if this could be added as an option to the Biblatex package.

Comment: If you need hyperlink one can add them -- I only wanted to avoid to complicate the code with more if-clauses. And one can add tests for non-numbers.

Comment: I have a follow-on question from my original post.  When I got the proofreader's feedback back from the press, they said that they wanted another tweak to the page ranges.  They say that numbers where the final two digits are in the teens (from 10-19) should not be elided down to a single digit.  So 211-212 should become 211-12, not 211-2; and 310-313 should be 310-13, not 310-3.  Is it possible to tweak Ulrike's solution to generate this output?  The proofreader says that this is a general requirement for books as stated in Hart's Rules for Compositors, so it's not just the rule of one press.

Comment: Well naturally it is possible. The numbers are there, so you only need to add more tests.

Comment: I'm glad it's possible. Unfortunately, I don't understand the logic of your code well enough to implement the tests.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The current values are in `\firstpagetemp` and `\abx@range@hold`. You should expand the \ifnum--\else-\fi clause for more tests. You can use \show to see their values and follow the logic.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to separate the digits of the page number in order to test them individually?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I'm posting here my modifications of Ulrike's code to add the additional tests to not elide page numbers in the teens as required by the press.  The code may be ugly, but I'm pleased that I discovered the xstring package, which permitted me to extract the digits without having to learn all about character processing in TeX.

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\firstpagetemp{}
\newcommand\printsecondrangevalue{}
\newcommand\myfirstleft{}\newcommand\mysecondleft{}
\newcommand\mysecondright{}\newcommand\mysecondtens{}
\def\printsecondrangevalue #1\bibrangedash #2{#2}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{pageref:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\abx@range@diff}{0}
  {\edef\firstpagetemp{\the\numexpr\abx@range@hold-\abx@range@diff}%
    \bibrangedash
    \StrGobbleRight{\firstpagetemp}{2}[\myfirstleft]%
    \ifdefempty{\myfirstleft}{\def\myfirstleft{0}}{}%
    \StrGobbleRight{\abx@range@hold}{2}[\mysecondleft]%
    \ifdefempty{\mysecondleft}{\def\mysecondleft{0}}{}%
    \StrRight{\abx@range@hold}{2}[\mysecondright]%
    \StrLeft{\mysecondright}{1}[\mysecondtens]%
    \ifthenelse{\myfirstleft=\mysecondleft \AND \mysecondtens=1}%
    {\mysecondright}%
    {%
    \def\blx@tempa{}%
    \protected\def\blx@range@out@value{\appto\blx@tempa}%
    \edef\next{\noexpand\blx@comprange@comp {\firstpagetemp}
    {\abx@range@hold}}%
    \next
    \expandafter\printsecondrangevalue\blx@tempa
    }%
    \def\abx@range@diff{0}}{}%
}
```

Comment: Could you make your example compilable?